# Html Parsing in Apex Class

Tags: apex, html, string, files, parser

I have a html template file available as attachment in one of my Salesforce object. It contains a proper html form with input tags and sub templates. Whenever I get a request from third party, which contains values for those input tags, I need to parse the HTML document and add the values to corresponding input tags and send the response in form of pdf file.

Do we have any libraries to parse the html content which I will take as string from attachment object, so I can append the value attributes to input tags ? Else I will have to use indexof, append concat methods etc to do all this stuff, which will be tedious for all the documents.

Comment: Not an answer to your question directly but is a html file your only option? A proper integration or XML file would be less fragile...

Comment: @Girbot It has to be HTML as same existing  templates we are using to generate dynamic forms which user fills and signs.  However in this new requirement, rather than user filling it, we need to take the values from API request and fill the templates and send back as response.

Comment: @identigral I can see the link provided say you have parser for XML.  But in my case we need to parse a proper html with input elements such as text,radio buttons, checkbox etc. I do not see XML dom parser helping here.

Comment: @PK SF _In the past, I've used these tools to parse HTML documents (since the structure is very simmilar)_